# Broken symmetry in presence of external confining field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, density-functional-theory

Suppose, there is a many particle system confined by an externally applied field. I have found in books that the system doesn't remain translationally invariant. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: You would have to be much more precise for anybody to be able to answer your question? What particles? What field? Which books?

Comment: I thought it is a general phenomenon. I am concerned with charged particles interacting via Yukawa Potential confined by harmonic oscillator potential.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. A harmonic oscillat0r potential already explicitly breaks the translational symmetry. Another possibility is that they're talking about *field-translational symmetry* which is actually an internal symmetry. This is clearly broken by an applied field because that singles out a 'direction' in the internal space. The easiest would be if you give the relevant quote, and include the reference.

Comment: I am just asking, how can I see mathematically the fact that application of harmonic oscillator potential breaks the translational symmetry.